# How do I convert a tribble to a list and convert function names?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr

I have a sample `tbl_df` that I created.  I'm looking to create a list that uses the `list_name` column for each list name, and fills in the list to match my `example_list` below.  In addition, I'd like to convert the character values from the `scrape_func` column to store the name of actual functions within the list.  I only used `mean` in the list as an example.

Sample `tbl_df`

```
example_df <-tibble::tribble(
   ~list_name, ~abbr,        ~id, ~scrape_func,
      "pepsi", "pep", "pepsi_id",       "mean",
       "coke",  "ck",  "coke_id",       "mean",
  "dr_pepper", "drp",    "dr_id",       "mean"
  )
```

Format of list that I am looking for:

```
example_list <- list(
  "pepsi" = list(
    list_name = "pepsi",
    abbr = "pep",
    id = "pepsi_id",
    scrape_func = mean
  ),
  "coke" = list(
    list_name = "coke",
    abbr = "ck",
    id = "coke_id",
    scrape_func = mean
  ),
  "dr_pepper" = list(
    list_name = "dr_pepper",
    abbr = "drp",
    id = "dr_id",
    scrape_func = mean
  )
)
```

I'm hoping to use a solution in the `tidyverse` if possible.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `get`  to get the value of the function and with `pmap` can loop over the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- example_df %>% 
         mutate(scrape_func = map(scrape_func, get)) %>%
         pmap(c) %>% 
         set_names(example_df$list_name)
```

checking with the expected output

```
all.equal(out, example_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or with `match.fun`

```
out <- example_df %>% 
         mutate(scrape_func = map(scrape_func, match.fun)) %>%
          pmap(c) %>% 
          set_names(example_df$list_name)
all.equal(out, example_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

If the OP wanted to store as a symbol, use `as.symbol` or `as.name` or with `rlang::sym` or `rlang::syms`

```
out2 <-  example_df %>%
            mutate(scrape_func = map(scrape_func, as.name)) %>%
            pmap(c) %>% 
            set_names(example_df$list_name)

out2$pepsi$scrape_func
#mean
```

We can get the values with `match.fun`

```
match.fun(out2$pepsi$scrape_func)
#function (x, ...) 
#UseMethod("mean")
#<bytecode: 0x7ffdc09fef58>
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  Is there a benefit to using get, or match.fun?  Also, what does pmap(c) do?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz `pmap`  `c` is concatenating the `list` column for each row into a `vector`. `match.fun` is more safe compared to `get`

Comment: Last question.  How do I print `out` to show the formatting of the list similar to example_list?  I want to store the list in my package.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz you meant `dput(example_list)` ?

Comment: No, I tried that, but I want the function details to be condensed/hidden like my example_list above.  I just want to see scrape_func = mean, not the whole mean function including useMethod, etc.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz then you may not need the `mutate(scrape_func = map(scrape_func, match.fun))` I was checking. your expected and in your expected, it is showed as function instead of character.  That is the reason `all.equal` returns TRUE

Comment: I wanted the output to look exactly like it did with how you did it.  I was just wondering if there was a way to condense scrape_func = mean with removing the quotes and recognizing it as a function similar to how I manually wrote it above.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz When you write it, it is just `mean` unquoted, but if you check the value inside, it includes all the details.  If there is some inequality, the `all.equal` will return FALSE

Comment: @Jazzmatazz can you just type `example_list$pepsi$scrape_func#
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x7ffdc09fef58>`

Comment: @Jazzmatazz can you please check my updated post.  I guess that would be the one you wanted

Comment: I think that should do it.  Please keep both solutions, as I'll probably have a use case for both.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
setNames(apply(example_df, 1, as.list), example_df$list_name)
#> $pepsi
#> $pepsi$list_name
#> [1] "pepsi"
#> 
#> $pepsi$abbr
#> [1] "pep"
#> 
#> $pepsi$id
#> [1] "pepsi_id"
#> 
#> $pepsi$scrape_func
#> [1] "mean"
#> 
#> 
#> $coke
#> $coke$list_name
#> [1] "coke"
#> 
#> $coke$abbr
#> [1] "ck"
#> 
#> $coke$id
#> [1] "coke_id"
#> 
#> $coke$scrape_func
#> [1] "mean"
#> 
#> 
#> $dr_pepper
#> $dr_pepper$list_name
#> [1] "dr_pepper"
#> 
#> $dr_pepper$abbr
#> [1] "drp"
#> 
#> $dr_pepper$id
#> [1] "dr_id"
#> 
#> $dr_pepper$scrape_func
#> [1] "mean"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate the response.  This didn't include the actual function in the list.  akrun's solution worked.